# WooCommerce:how to get data from a link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce store all the products are in an iframe. Click the add to cart button the product is added using this link

```
http://samelink/%D1%81art/?add-to-cart=24&quantity=1&file=1586786694
```

I need to get the file name (file=1586786694)from the link while transferring the product to the cart and save it as a variable.I found that the goods are transferred to the basket using woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect.
Help solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following, that should save the "file" value as custom cart item data:

```
// Add "file" value as custom cart item data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filter_add_cart_item_data_callback', 10, 3 );
function filter_add_cart_item_data_callback( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['file'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['file']       = wc_clean( $_REQUEST['file'] );
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() ); // Make each item unique
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Then you will be able to get it from cart item using `$cart_item['file']`…

The following code will display you "file" value in cart items *(Just for check)*:

```
// Display "file" value custom cart item data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'filter_get_item_data_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_get_item_data_callback( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['service'] ) ) {

        if ( isset( $cart_item['file'] ) && $file = $cart_item['file'] ) {
            $cart_item_data[] = array(
                'key'     => __("File"),
                'value'   => $file,
            );
        }
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.